# chrome.tabs.getCurrent() or tabs.query()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Both methods are producing the same error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined` for my content script... I've already looked at [How to fetch URL of current Tab in my chrome extension using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436245/how-to-fetch-url-of-current-tab-in-my-chrome-extention-using-javascript) and [How do you use chrome.tabs.getCurrent to get the page object in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718256/how-do-you-use-chrome-tabs-getcurrent-to-get-the-page-object-in-a-chrome-extensi) though I'm still not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Extension Tester",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Tester",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/"],
      "js": [
        "inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

inject.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
  console.log(tabs[0].id);
});
```

or

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {
  console.log(tab.id);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome.tabs returns undefined in content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034859/chrome-tabs-returns-undefined-in-content-script)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate [chrome.tabs returns undefined in content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034859/chrome-tabs-returns-undefined-in-content-script)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cannot use `chrome.tabs` in content script,you need to use `chrome.runtime`
To know the tab id of the content script, first use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to send a message, and the background page receive it.

Using `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`, the callback function is

`function(any message, MessageSender sender, function sendResponse) {...};`

so, you will know the tab id by `sender.id`

Comment: nice answer, but I have a doubt. The message sent from the content script througth chrome.runtime.sendMessage will be received by any extension that have called chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener, right?

Comment: @rmpt I believe no. addListener and sendMessage work only for the current extension. There is another API to interact between extensions.

Comment: This is almost right, though for the tab ID you actually need to do `sender.tab.id` like they suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202953/obtaining-this-tab-id-from-content-script-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/tabs#method-getCurrent says "Gets the tab that this script call is being made from. Returns undefined if called from a non-tab context (for example, a background page or popup view)."

Comment: Just post the working code example