# Automatically Type In Current Tab Search Bar-Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am just learning JavaScript primarily to automate searches on a specific website and compare some data that is gathered from those searches. Thus I was wondering if it would be possible to do such a thing with a search bar in that site with JavaScript in my chrome extension I want to create.

*Note: an example of a search bar in a website would be like [YouTube's](https://www.youtube.com/) search bar*

Edit: After doing far more research, I found that `forum.submit` might be of use, but I am not too sure.

EDIT 2:

**extension_ui.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>extension_ui</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Start</button>
    <script src="find_time_slots.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

**find_time_slots.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',onclick,false)

    function onclick(res){
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            res.tabNum,
            {code: 'document.getElementById("search").value = "overwatch";'}
          );
        })
    }

},false)
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
    sendResponse({tabNum: sender.id})
});
```

Although I am not getting any errors, it does not update the search bar(on youtube) to ethier have "overwatch" as its value or show up in the youtube page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need find the id of search bar. In youtube the id is `search`;

In your popup.js using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` and it need put in a listener event.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tabs[0].id,
    {code: 'document.getElementById("search").value = "' + /*you value*/ + '";'}
  );
});
```

Hope that can help you

Comment: so the /*you value*/ would be the value I want to put in, like 'JavaScript Tutorials' ?
Also, this was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Now that I think about it, when I run the script, do I need to click search to commence the search? or does it do it automatically?

Comment: that depend on your code. If you want that automatic. Make sure the code run after page load.

Comment: Now I have a permissions error. Any idea how to fix it? 
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.

Edit: I fixed the permissions by adding "activeTab" in manifest

Comment: add the url page you want to access to permissions key in your ```manifest.json``` file

Comment: Now I have another error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Comment: like this ```"permissions": ["activeTab","declarativeContent", "storage", "*://example.com/*"],```

Comment: you can check the error ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined``` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415925/chrome-tabs-getcurrent-or-tabs-query